# Target initialization failed. Failed to cache rpm database (1)

Tags: root, rpm, zypper, dropbox

I am running an openSUSE leap 42.2  64 bit os on my laptop. I was trying to install some packages including nautilus-dropbox, so I added the packman repo.
After zypper update, there were some packages that couldn't be updated because of repo's conflicts. So I tried to install them. At some point one packages was  failed to be installed. Then when I am running any zypper command I am getting this error:

```
Target initialization failed.
Failed to cache rpm database (1).
```

What does this mean? And how can I fix it?

I checked `df -h /` and I was surprised to see that the root partition occupies 31G on my disk that 100% used space!

Is it possible that dropbox occupies space on my root / partition?

Comment: Though not the problem in this case, the same message can result from a corrupt package database. At https://www.suse.com/documentation/sles11/book_sle_admin/data/sec_zypper.html, in section 6.1.8, _Troubleshooting_ we see that one can refresh and rebuild the database with `zypper refresh -fdb`, and that solved my problem when I had the above message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you stated your root partition has no space left. Clean up to get some space on it and try it again. Have a look in /tmp /var/tmp /var/log for things you don't need any more.
Additionally check if your /home directory is also in the root partition. If yes, dropbox could take the space on your root partition.

Comment: df -h returns /dev/sda6        47G  8.0G   39G  18% /home  and on the other hand   /dev/sda5        31G   31G   64K 100% /

Comment: du -sh .snapshots returns  : 698G .snapshots    What is this directory?

Comment: Is it safe to clean the directories /tmp /var/tmp and /var/log ?

Comment: Ok I deleted some snapshots and it worked! :)